# How to render block editor in wp-admin custom pages programmatically

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I created a page using WP block editor and I want to edit the content of that page in a different custom page in WP admin section but when I am trying to render the content in wp_editor function then it is not working to render as shown in block editor while I was creating it.
Example code I am using is:

```
wp_editor(
    $page->post_content,
    'page_content',
    array(
        'media_buttons' => true,
        'teeny' => true,
        'supports' => array('editor')
    )
);
```

Original block editor content looks like this:
[image]

And after adding my codes in custom page, it looks something like this:
[image]

What I am trying here is: I want to edit the content as like block editor in my custom page but somehow something is wrong. Please help!

Comment: This looks like an X Y problem. If you want to add a WP Admin menu link to edit a specific page, that's doable without doing any of the things in your question

Comment: @TomJNowell Can you suggest something on how to render my content of gutenberg in editor programmatically?

Comment: or you can add a direct link to the edit page interface for that post to the admin menu, but if you have other controls on that page that are not `wp_editor` then that won't be feasible. How you might link directly is a different question though

Comment: Rendering the block editor on a custom page is presently [a pretty involved procedure](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor/) - one lengthy and complicated enough that I would not expect to see an answer which bothers to detail the process. If you can provide more information about why you are trying to render a block editor on a custom page, it might be possible to recommend a more feasible alternative as Tom has alluded.

Comment: @bosco I am trying to remove or hide some block setting options, wants to show edit and hide block option to normal user so that they can either edit block or hide any block..